# SQL query for below condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select

```
Employee_id    Status 
-----------------------
111            Approved
111            Approved
111            Pending
222            Approved
222            Approved
```

In my table which is like above only 222 should get as approved give solution.

What I've tried:

```
select distinct employee_id, status
from main_table
```

Comment: Describe why you want that answer. And also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: select distinct employee_id,status from main_table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT employee_id
FROM main_table
WHERE employee_id NOT IN (SELECT s.employee_id FROM main_table as s
                          WHERE Status != 'Approved')
```

Comment: I know it's not the case here, but I prefer NOT EXISTS before NOT IN since NOT IN is a bit tricky when it comes to NULL values. Always stick to NOT EXISTS and you're safe!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for employees that don't have any status except "Approved". This can be expressed as a `not exists` condition:

```
SELECT DISTINCT employee_id
FROM   main_table a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   main_table b
                   WHERE  a.employee_id = b.employee_id AND
                          b.status != 'Approved')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT employee_id
  FROM main_table a
 GROUP BY employee_id
HAVING sum( case status when 'Approved' then 0 else 1 end ) = 0
```